# How to use widget lists in ListView.builder?

Tags: android, flutter, android-widget, flutter-dependencies, flutter-widget

```
class CardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  String title;
  String description;
  CardPage({Key key,this.title,this.description}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Container(
      height: (108),
      child: Card(
        semanticContainer: true,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.white54,
          ),
          child: ListTile(
              title: Text(title,
                  style: themeData.textTheme.headline2),
              trailing: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                child: Wrap(
                  spacing: 6,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(Icons.fastfood, size: 25),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(description,
                  style: themeData.textTheme.subtitle1)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my CardPage class. And this is my FavoritePage class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'card_page.dart';

class FavoritesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  List<CardPage> cardList;

  FavoritesPage({Key key,
  this.cardList,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FavoritesPage> createState() => _FavoritesPageState();
}

class _FavoritesPageState extends State<FavoritesPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body:SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount:widget.cardList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return widget.cardList;
            }
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, i want to use widget.cardList in listView.builder but the error says:

```
The return type 'List<CardPage>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.
```

I just want to create a favoritePage like there are a lot of cards and i wanted to paste it another page which name is favoritePage but i couldn't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, you are ignoring the index..
use it like this:

```
 return widget.cardList[index];
```

Comment: basic but it worked :) thanks i forgot to add index

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a list of widgets you dont have to add a ListView.builder

```dart
return Scaffold(
      body:SafeArea(
       child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
        mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min,
         children : widget.cardList,
        )
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. I hope this will solve your problem.

```
 body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: cities.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    //..................................................ListTile
      return ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          child: Text(cities[index].cityName[index][0]),
        ),
        title: Text(cities[index].cityName),
        subtitle: Text(cities[index].countryName),
        trailing: Text("\$" + prices[index]),
      );
    },
  ),
```